# How to install Remastersys

Tags: live-cd

I had ubuntu 11.04 LTS running and had installed remastersys. Now that I have upgraded my system to ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, was trying to install remastersys again. The website says development of remastersys has been stopped and there is no hint as how to install it. Somebody please help me install remastersys?
Also, is there any way that I can create the copy of my installation of ubuntu with all its applications..?

Answer (score 0):

If development has stopped you can try installing from source, but you may be out of luck.

I suggest you use alternate tools. INO easiest (and best) tool are the debian live scripts.

http://live.debian.net/

**http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man7/live-build.7.html**

The package is available in Ubuntu. It takes some time to read, but, IMO, the reuslting iso is much nicer and much easier to customize.

http://live.debian.net/manual/current/html/live-manual.en.html

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch